# Laravel Echo cannot subscribe to Pusher private channel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, pusher, laravel-echo

I am not able to [listen to an event in a private channel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/broadcasting#using-example-application). However, I can listen to public channel.

**The problem**

This works:

```
Echo.channel('Foo.Bar')
    .listen('MyEvent', (e) => {
        console.log('It worked!');
    });
```

I can see in Pusher Debug Console that there are three consecutive events:

1. CONNECTION
2. SUBSCRIBED
3. OCCUPIED

Plus, if I send `Channel: Foo.Bar; Event: App\Events\MyEvent`, I can see the output in my browser console.

However, this doesn't work:

```
Echo.private('Foo.Bar')
    .listen('MyEvent', (e) => {
        console.log('It privately worked!');
    });
```

I do not see the subscription in the Pusher Debug Console. Obviously, if I send `Channel: private-Foo.Bar; Event: App\Events\MyEvent`, I do not see an output in my browser console.

**What I did**

1. Added `Broadcast::routes();` in the `boot()` method of `BroadcastServiceProvider`
2. Added `Broadcast::channel('Foo.Bar', function ($user, $FooBarId) {return true;});` 
   in the `boot()` method of `BroadcastServiceProvider`
3. Have a [queue working with supervisor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queues#supervisor-configuration).
4. Have my `config\broadcasting` set up properly with app, key, secret, driver, cluster, encrypt. (I can send event from my app to Pusher)

**Side notes**

I can send and listen to *public* events with my app. It is only when the channel becomes private that I am not able to *listen* (my app can send events on private channel to Pusher).

I suspect it is probably related to authentication because `Broadcast::channel('Foo.Bar', callback)` in the `BroadcastServiceProvider` is not being executed.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I am frustrated with this as well. Did you ever find anything?

Comment: @Derek See the accepted answer

Comment: Check my Detail Answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72574972/14308480) Hope this will Help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `config\app`, you need to uncomment the following line

```
App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class
```

See [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/broadcasting#configuration)