# Laravel Broadcasting

Tags: php, laravel, pusher

**My Scenario**

Im trying to get laravel to work with pusher without the use of laravel echo, everything works on a public channel but when i switch to a private channel in the `broadcastOn()` method of my event pusher on the frontend doesn't pick anything up anymore. It gets logged in my pusher applications event log as a private channel but pusher on the frontend just sais no.

I've set up and returned true for the channel code like this:

```
Broadcast::channel('application', function ($post, $username) {
    if(true){
        return true;
    }
});
```

This is my event code:

```
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new PrivateChannel('application');
}
```

The class implements `ShouldBroadcast` and lastly here is my front end code:

```
 <script>
    //instantiate a Pusher object with our Credential's key
    var pusher = new Pusher('MY_KEY', {
        cluster: 'en',
        encrypted: true
    });

    //Subscribe to the channel we specified in our Laravel Event
    var channel = pusher.subscribe('application');

    //Bind a function to a Event (the full Laravel class)
    channel.bind('App\\Events\\PostMessage', function(){
        console.log('Event Logged');
    });
</script>
```

**My Question**

Why is my pusher front end code not detecting my private broadcast?

Comment: Review this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41728930/laravel-broadcasting-auth-always-fails-with-403-error/73511470#73511470

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hehehe I think I found it:
https://pusher.com/docs/client_api_guide/client_private_channels

You need to prefix the channel name with `'private-'`. One of the things Echo does automatically for you!

Here's the rest for reference. The final advice still stands and would've at least helped you with debugging this issue ;-)

---

A few things you want to check when using Pusher *without* `Echo` in Laravel:

- Make sure you have your cluster set correctly. I just checked my own
  dashboard and had `mt1` as a cluster. It could be the defaults are
  obsolete.
- Echo is set up to do a lot of things out of sight. One of those is
  converting easy to remember strings to their full namespaced
  counterparts when communicating with Pusher. So if you want to skip
  Echo, you want to make sure you emulate this behaviour 1 on 1, or
  else it will break.

On that last note, it could be that you need to do something like this:

```
var channel = pusher.subscribe('App/Events/application');
```

- Try copying the docs 1 on 1 as well, adding some code that make the
  channel unique. I don't know the internals, but it could be that the
  `PrivateChannel` requires a unique parameter, and doesn't function
  without:

Like this:

```
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new PrivateChannel('order.'.$this->update->order_id);
}
```

And then for your channel:

```
Broadcast::channel('order.{orderId}', function ($user, $orderId) {
    return $user->id === Order::findOrNew($orderId)->user_id;
});
```

Try using `Echo` first, to get everything running following the docs. It provides a great layer of convenience. Then break it down from there. At least that way you know you have all the basics down and communications between your app and Pusher are working! :-)

That's all I could think of right now without actually coding it myself! Hope one of them works for you.

Comment: Hmm thanks for this, ill remake it again (Got stressed removed the app and decided to try out echo, got it work) and see if this is the case. The only reason i wanted to not use echo is because they dont document where to put each piece of javascript code very well. I managed to find out by going over to another site and looking through the code. but the main reason is im not too familiar with vue components / javascript in itself. But thanks for this again ill test it out and get back to you!

Comment: Gave it a look through again and with a few extra changes i was able to get it working! thanks a lot for this its helped so much. Huge learning curve

Comment: @Stan Smulders, Seems you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45877837/how-can-i-make-realtime-notification-for-user-who-are-not-login